# Pandas apply groupby list to column containing list

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
Col1    Col2
A       'AD'
A       ['FG', 'LKL']
B       ['FGT']
```

I am trying the following:

```
df.groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list)
```

I get the following:

```
Col1    Col2
A       ['AD', "['FG', 'LKL']"]
B       ['FGT']
```

I need to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2
A       ['AD', 'FG', 'LKL']
B       ['FGT']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `explode`

```
out = df.explode('Col2').groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list)
```

Comment: The explode doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the lists are not string ? Because **explode** does not work on string type lists.